# Turf Envelope returns 5 array coordinates for rectangle polygon

Tags: polygon, mapbox-gl-js, extents, turf

I'm trying to understand why [`turf.envelope()`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#envelope) returns 5 coordinate arrays.  I'd expect to see only 4.  Is this normal/expected behavior?

I ask because I'm currently trying to debug an issue I'm having while setting a bounding box in MapBox after being supplied ***x*** amount of coordinate arrays from the draw control from the [`draw.update`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/master/docs/API.md#drawupdate) event and I'm wondering if this may be the culprit.

I'm leaning toward having 5 coordinate arrays being returned not being the issue, because everything functions as expected when processing the [`draw.create`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/master/docs/API.md#drawcreate) event.

Comment: my guess is that the fifth point represents the center of the envelop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is returning a [polygon](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#polygon) which must have the start and end point the same to close the polygon.